# Swift 2.0: Loop through JSON array with NSDictionary

Tags: json, xcode, swift, loops, swift2

I am getting this json from a url, the return JSON is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Mary"},{"id":2,"name":"John"}]
```

My Swift2 Code is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var NumberOfArtists = 0

    var NameOfArtist = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        parseJSON()

    }

    func parseJSON(){

        do {

            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zzzzzz.com/API/name.php")!)

            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

            let NumberOfArtists = jsonResult.count

           **LOOP THROUGH THE JSON ARRAY**

        } catch let error as NSError {

            print(error)

        }
    }
}
```

How can I loop through the JSON array to put which name in a cell on a Table View?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your json is returning an array you can do something like this to loop your response and populate your `NameOfArtist` array:

```
if let json = jsonResult as? NSArray {
    for item in json {
        if let name = item.valueForKey("name") {
            NameOfArtist.append(name as! String)
        }
    }
}
```